# How to set replyTo address for Laravel notifications?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm getting

> "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage::replyTo() in ... /TeamMessage.php:68"

I tried to set the replyTo address for notifications like this in  TeamMessage.php:

```
    public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->replyTo('myemail@gmail.com', 'My Name')
        ->line($this->custom_message)
}
```

I'm guessing it isn't possible to set header info here? Is there another way?I'm using the replyTo() method described at https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/MailMessage.html

*Edit* To add some clarification: I need to be able to set the reply-to address dynamically, so it won't work to hardcode it in a config somewhere.

Comment: hi there, did you check if that class library exist in your project?

Comment: I have notifications working fine already, if that's what you mean. It just fails when I try to add the replyTo method. I assume I don't need a separate library for that?

Comment: Try `return (new MailMessage())->replyTo...`, or use the `with()` method

Comment: @Derek forgive my ignorance, but how is your first suggestion different from my code, aside form the extra parentheses? And how do you use the "with()" method in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error makes no sense at all. This method is present in MailMessage, the only thing that would make sense is a missing method in your version of the repository. `replyTo()` is kind of new (nov 2016), so did you

```
composer update
```

?

This is the related commit:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/484cfcbdb381e8f36510030b086884e49b898e87

Comment: Hah! I had no idea replyTo() was that new, let alone that it had only been introduced in the last patch. Thank you so much. It works as expected.